# mp3 file format

Tags: java, mp3

I want to know the version of a mp3 file format.

What should I do?

I am reading file properties with java programs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website [wotsit.org](http://www.wotsit.org/) has specifications and descriptions of file formats. Wikipedia is also often a good starting point. Read [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) on Wikipedia.

If your goal is just to read the metadata from MP3 files (track title, artist name, etc.): That information is stored in [ID3 tags](http://www.id3.org/) inside the file. There are several Java libraries available for reading ID3 tags. Google for "java id3" and you'll find them.

Comment: Jasper
I am not using any library, as this project has restriction to use any thing else than java core. :( 

So these are not a option. 

my project needs to read metadata form any MP3 file. But after going through many docs on ID3 subject. i got to know there are many versions for this. like id3v1, 

so how should I find which version of file format is being used by a MP3 file.

Comment: You would have to search the beginning and end of the file; there is no other indication of the presence or absence of ID3v1 or ID3v2 tags; it is entirely possible both will be present. (Ugh: not using any libraries is an absolutely ridiculous limitation for anything but homework.)

Comment: well, i have downloaded a library and trying to copy code from.

i think i will be able to get out with my homework.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use third-party libraries, then there's nothing you can do except for programming it yourself. The ID3 website (link is in my answer above) has good documentation, I think it's not that hard to write a basic ID3 reader program yourself.